# Close responsive menu

Tags: javascript, menu, responsive

I have a response menu which works great. However, I want the menu to be closed when the visitor clicks on an item in my menu. At this moment, the menu closes only when the visitor clicks on the 'button_menu'. The menu must stay open if someone clicks on 'submenu-button'. How can I do this?

```
    <script>
(function($) {
$.fn.menumaker = function(options) {  
 var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
   format: "dropdown",
   sticky: false
 }, options);
 return this.each(function() {
   $(this).find(".button_menu").on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
     var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
     if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
       mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
     }
     else {
       mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
       if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
         mainmenu.find('ul').show();
       }
     }
   });
   cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
multiTg = function() {
     cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
     cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
       if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
         $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
       else {
         $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
     });
   };
   if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
   else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
   if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
resizeFix = function() {
  var mediasize = 1000;
     if ($( window ).width() > mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').show();
     }
     if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
     }
   };
   resizeFix();
   return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
 });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   format: "multitoggle"
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<header>
            <nav id="cssmenu">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="http://www. .com">
                    <img alt="" src="images/logo.png"></a> </div>
                <div id="head-mobile">
                </div>
                <div class="button_menu">
                </div>
                <ul id="myTopnav" class="navigation">
                    <li class="active" data-slide="1">
                    <a onclick="myFunction()">HOME</a></li>
                    <li data-slide="2"><a onclick="myFunction()">PRODUCTS</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                        <a onclick="window.location.href='http://www.'">
                        ROTARY STAGES</a></li>
                        <li>
                        <a onclick="window.location.href='http://www.'">
                        LINEAR STAGES</a></li>
                        <li>
                        <a onclick="window.location.href='http://www.'">
                        MULTI-DOF STAGES</a></li>
                        <li>
                        <a onclick="window.location.href='http://www.'">
                        DRIVERS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li data-slide="4"><a onclick="myFunction()">TRADE FAIRS</a></li>
                    <li data-slide="6"><a onclick="myFunction()">COMPANY</a></li>
                    <li data-slide="16"><a onclick="myFunction()">TECHNOLOGY</a></li>
                    <li data-slide="8"><a onclick="myFunction()">CAREERS</a></li>
                    <li data-slide="10"><a onclick="myFunction()">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply attach the click event to the `ul` within your `.menumaker`, and check whether the original target of the click was within a `.submenu-button` to determine whether to close:

```js
return this.each(function() {
   $(this).find(".button_menu").on('click', function(){
     // Your current button event remains the same
   }).next('ul').on('click.checkToClose', function(e) {
       var target = e.originalEvent.target;
       if ($(target).closest('.submenu-button').length === 0) {
           $(this).slideToggle().removeClass('open');
       }
   });
   // ...
});
```

Or, if you'd like to close only if a menu link has been clicked, it can be even more brief:

```js
return this.each(function() {
   // ...
   var mainmenu = $(this).find(".button_menu").next('ul');
   mainmenu.on('click.checkToClose', 'a', function(e) {
       if ($(this).closest('.submenu-button').length === 0) {
           mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
       }
   });
   // ...
});
```